# Multiple function onClick javascript

Tags: javascript

Multiple functions on js not executing the first one does but the second one doesnt

`onClick="javascript:${ formId }(${ peopleId }, 'userSettingsAddAccountNotificationsModify') contactMethodPopUp() "`

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

You're going about it the wrong way what you could do is have one function onClick and then execute the other inside the that first function.

```
<button onclick="firstFunc()"><button/>

<script>
function firstfunc(){
 //do something
  secondFunc()
}

function secondFunc(){
 //do something
}
<script/>
```

Comment: that is not multiple listeners

Comment: I am not clear on how to add this javascript:${ formId }(${ peopleId }, 'userSettingsAddAccountNotificationsModify') in aseparate function as this was done by another developer

Answer (score 0):

Use [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) instead of setting the onclick attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You can put multiple functions in onclick like this:

```
onclick="alert('hey'); console.log('hey');"
```